# Symfony 2 installation: "Could not open input file"?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to install Symfony 2 and I'm almost there. The guide said that I have to make sure that my system is properly configured for Symfony, so I have to type in

"php app/check.php"

in the terminal. As a result, I get

"Could not open input file: app/check.php"

Any ideas on solving this problem?

Comment: If you have installed Symfony successfully you can check the requirements by hitting url `.../web/config.php`, too; otherwise let us know what's your OS, where did you run the `php app/check.php`? Is your phpunit defined and environment variable?

Comment: I'm on a Macbook 10.5.8, I have MAMP which lets me run php 5.3. I'm just using a terminal and I input the commands in there like "$ php app/check.php" Also, I don't know what you mean by your last question. Sorry, I'm kind of a noob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are in the correct path before running the command:

```
cd directory_path
php app/check.php
```

replace "directory_path" above with whatever path that contains the "app" directory that Symfony wants to check.

In your concrete example:

```
cd Documents/Symfony
php app/check.php
```

You just have to make sure that you are in the correct directory when running php. You change the current directory with "cd" like above.

If it still stays it cannot find the file, you can try closing and opening terminal again (which will reset your current directory) or use

```
cd ~/Documents/Symfony
php app/check.php
```

(~ should resolve to your home directory)

Comment: My directory path is "Documents/Symfony/app/check.php". This time, after typing, "cd Documents/Symfony/app/check.php", I got "Documents/Symfony/app/check.php: No such file or directory"

Comment: Hm.. I tried typing "cd Documents/Symfony" like you said, but it still says that there's no such file or directory :(

Comment: Find out exactly where on your mac "Symfony" is.

Comment: oh thank you!!!! I used "cd ~/Documents/Symfony" and it worked like a charm! You're awesome!